# fprintf (serial communication) in matlab

Tags: string, matlab, printf

I'm trying to communicate with differential drive mobile robot via matlab functions and .mex files. I can succesfully move the robot with command:

```
ref = serial('COM1');
set(ref,'BaudRate', 9600);
fopen(ref);

fprintf(ref,'C,1000,1000');
out = fscanf(ref)

fclose(ref)
delete(ref)
```

However, the function that I made which includes `fprintf` does not work:

```
function r = Move(ref,left,right)

fprintf(ref,'C,left,right');
out = fscanf(ref)
```

I'am aware that the problem is different string used  in command `fprintf` (i.e. 'C,1000,1000' is not equal to 'C,left,right'), but I can't resolve this problem. Sorry if this is too trivial.

The ANSWER is (see comments below):

```
function r = Move(ref,left,right)

fprintf(ref,sprintf('C,%d,%d', left, right));
out = fscanf(ref);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
function r = Move(ref,left,right)

fprintf(ref,'C,%d,%d', left, right);
out = fscanf(ref)
```

Comment: @Makaroni With which arguments do you call the `move` function? `move(ref, 1000, 1000)`?

Comment: Yes, basically. I can put any number from 0 to 20000 when calling the function `Move`.

Comment: Just testing: Does it work when you place `fprintf(ref,'C,1000,1000');` within the function?

Comment: Did you try whether the formatted string looks correct? E.g. by placing `sprintf('C,%d,%d', left, right)` within the function (without closing semicolon).

Comment: Yes, it worked! Thank you very very much! The answer is `fprintf(ref,sprintf('C,%d,%d', left, right));
out = fscanf(ref) `